# Mysql select query in single table and where condition in other row

Tags: mysql

table name: employee

```
sr | name  | head_id
--------------------
1  | rahul | 2
2  | amit  | 0
3  | john  | 1
```

Desired Output:

```
sr | name  | head_id | head_name
---------------------------------
1  | rahul | 2       | amit
2  | amit  | 0       | 
3  | john  | 1       | rahul
```

I want a query where I can get the head_name according to their head_id

Comment: You have to use ` join`

Comment: Nick,that was his second table i think,not desired output

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all to achieve what you want?

Comment: Please show your code first. stack overflow is not code factory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `join` to get the desired output.

```
select e.sr,e.name,e.head_id,e1.name 
from employee e
join employee e1 on e.head_id = e1.sr
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JOIN like this:

```
SELECT * FROM employee e JOIN head h ON h.id = e.head_id
```